# Como se puede crear un área circular y que las bolas se queden en el centro 2D

Tags: unity, unity2d

Tengo una consulta por que no se si se puede hacer en unity en 2D. En la captura de abajo, el circulo es el area o ring. Y por uno de sus orificios salen esferas, la idea es que con las físicas. Las esferas queden en el centro de la pantalla, como podéis ver en la captura 2. ¿Se puede hacer en 2D, este efecto?, todo los tutoriales que he buscado las físicas, siempre caen hacia abajo, pero lo que quiero es que se queden todas en el centro del area/ring.

Captura 1.
[image: Captura 1.]
[image: Captura 1.]

Captura 2.

Comment: Me parece que lo que buscas es usar `PointEffector` https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PointEffector2D.html. echa un vistazo a la documentación.

Comment: Gracias @Jakala, voy ha probar lo que me has mencionado